# Strange file appeared by itself and wouldn't let me delete. Then later disappeared

Tags: 20.04, security, malware, antivirus

Hopefully what happened is normal and it's just my general ignorance regarding these things. I know linux doesn't often get viruses but other strange things have been happening on my system recently, plus I have an enemy that had hacked my windows computer before to spy on me, hence why I moved to ubuntu.

---

In the program Openshot there is a profile folder that is always empty unless you create a custom profile. I added a text file to the empty folder with new profile settings. It's important to note that openshot wouldn't have read that text file as I had made a mistake, so the program openshot wouldn't have noticed anything different.

When I returned to delete the file, I noticed another file there. It was a text file. I was unable to delete it. After googling whether openshot profile should have other files and finding out it should be empty I returned to find the file gone. The only parts of the name I remember are the word 'streaming' and near the end it was either 'gootv' or 'gotv.'

When I checked my rubbish bin the file wasn't there, but other previous files I'd put there were.

I know this isn't a lot to go on. Is there a way to check what files were deleted by the system or what should I do? I have clam anti virus installed but it doesn't allow for a whole system scan so I'm unsure.

System Details:

```
OpenShot Version 2.5.1-dev-2 / ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS
```

Comment: Insufficient data. Maybe it was normal operation, maybe it was malware. Your Ubuntu system does not log every system file deletion. Creating and deleting files, including temporary files and hidden files, is a part of normal operation.

Comment: I apologise for insufficient data. I just don't know what to do. Any keywords for things I can google to be able to provide the data? @user535733

Comment: Seems like the data does not exist to make the question answerable: You don't know the filename, and there's no log you can check to find it. Your *real* question "*was this an intrusion?*" cannot be answered.

Comment: I see. I thought there might be a command to show every process of the system or something so I could find the file in question?

Comment: That's a good Search Engine question: Try "linux command to show all processes"...but it won't help you to find a deleted file.

Comment: I appreciate your help, truly. But it seems so strange that linux wouldn't have some way to check whether I've been compromised or to check some sort of log. It's linux, not windows!@user535733

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have said, there's insufficient data here to give you any solid answers.

There's many ways to prevent a file from being deleted by a user -- the easiest is for the directory permissions to prevent the user from being able to write to the directory. (This can be done even if the user owns the directory in question. The permissions are applied even if the user could modify the permissions.)

The file could also be set 'immutable' via the `chattr(1)`, or the programmatic interface that it uses.

The directory could also be on a read-only filesystem.

The process you're using to try to delete the file could also be confined by a security tool such as AppArmor, SELinux (unlikely on Ubuntu), Seccomp, Firejail, etc. (This is probably unlikely for a shell that you start via terminal on your system.)

Usually programs do not delete files through a 'rubbish bin' sort of system. That's provided by whatever desktop interface you're using, and most programs do not use it. Deleted files are just *gone* unless you've got something like zfs snapshots or lvm snapshots to maintain data even beyond deletion.

You can watch short-lived files come and go using the `filelife-bpfcc` tool from the `bpfcc-tools` package:

```
$ sudo filelife-bpfcc 
[sudo] password for sarnold: 
TIME     PID    COMM             AGE(s)  FILE
03:14:34 1400939 mutt             0.00    mutt-millbarge-1000-1400939-6602
03:14:41 1400939 mutt             0.00    mutt-millbarge-1000-1400939-6795
03:14:45 1400939 mutt             0.00    mutt-millbarge-1000-1400939-2043
03:14:45 1400939 mutt             0.00    1350509210-80274.tmp
```

You can watch which files programs use via the `opensnoop-bpfcc` tool from the `bpfcc-tools` package:

```
$ sudo opensnoop-bpfcc 
PID    COMM               FD ERR PATH
6454   thermald            9   0 /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/intel-rapl:0:2/energy_uj
6454   thermald            9   0 
6454   thermald            9   0 /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone5/temp
10101  i3status            4   0 /sys/class/net/enp0s31f6/uevent
10101  i3status            4   0 /sys/class/net/virbr0/uevent
```